# How to Add icon on dialogue in angular-material

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material, mddialog

I am using Angular-material in my project. where I want show Dialogue for which I am using

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title(modalObject.header)
            .content(modalObject.text)
            .ok(modalObject.control)
        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            var status = 'You decided to get rid of your debt.';
        }, function () {
            status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
        });
```

My requirement is I have to Icon with Header or inside body anywhere to show this dialogue is for what.
eg : Error, Warning and success

but I am not able to achieve this.

can anyone please tell me how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include this in a function.. like..

```
    $scope.showConfirm = function (ev){

var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title(modalObject.header)
            .content(modalObject.text)
            .ok(modalObject.control)
        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            var status = 'You decided to get rid of your debt.';
        }, function () {
            status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
        });

};
```

and call this either by HTML. like `ng-click="showConfirm()"`

or call the function from inside a controller simply by `$scope.showConfirm();`

make sure you have the correct controller assigned to your content.

Comment: Thanks for reply but Please read the question once again I asked different thing. My question was how can I put icons inside dialogue body not how to call or how to show dialogue

Answer (score 0):

For some reason , the `title` and `textContent` of md-dialog doesn't bind to Html .One alternative is to use the template option and explicitly add icons to your template :

```
$mdDialog.show({
  scope: $scope,        
  preserveScope: true,           
  template: '<md-dialog>' +
              '  <md-dialog-content>' +
              '     <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>{{modalObject.text}} -With icon' +  //Icon
              '  </md-dialog-content>' +
              '</md-dialog>'                 
  }
});
```